# TinMce value not posting in Yii

Tags: php, post, yii, tinymce

Here is my code of textarea in View Page

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'content'); ?>    
<?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'content', array('class' => 'tinymce', 'title' => 'Please enter Content','style'=> 'width:100%')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'content'); ?>
```

While posting I am not getting this value in Controller. Please help with me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the content of the tinyMCE editor to the textarea on submit.

```
$('form#form_id').on('submit', function() {
    tinyMCE.get('TinyMCEId').save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using                                                                                                 var contentText= tinyMCE.get('Locations_address').getContent();
$('#Locations_address').val(contentText);                                                          And to set value of textarea  to tinymce    tinyMCE.get("Locations_address").setContent($("#Locations_address").val());.